# Usar extension responsive en Datatables y Vue 3

Tags: datatables, vue3

Tengo una aplicacion que corre el plugin datatables y funciona muy bien, pero me gustaria añadir la extension de comportamiento responsive del datatable pero me devuelve un error de tipado porque estoy usando TypeScript en Vue, alguna idea de como utilizar esta extension?

La instale con el npm segun la documentacion de Datatables asi:

```js
npm install --save datatables.net-dt
npm install --save datatables.net-responsive-dt
```

He probado esto sin exito (omito algunos datos no requeridos para el ejemplo):

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import DataTable from 'datatables.net-vue3'
import 'datatables.net-responsive-dt'


let options = {  
  responsive: true
}
</script>
```

Tambien intente esto:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import DataTable from 'datatables.net-vue3'
import Responsive from 'datatables.net-responsive-dt'


let options = {  
  responsive: true
}
</script>
```

La documentacion no es clara en como usar la extension

Answer (score 0):

Revisando un ejemplo posteado en stackblitz logre implementar el plugin de manera correcta ahora, primero actualizando las dependencias del package.json a:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "datatables.net-responsive-dt": "^2.4.0",
    "datatables.net-vue3": "^2.0.0",
    ...
}
```

y luego en el archivo Vue

```
import DataTable from 'datatables.net-vue3'
import DataTablesLib from 'datatables.net'
import Responsive from 'datatables.net-responsive-dt'

Datatable.use(Responsive)

let options = {
  responsive: true
}
```

y finalmente importando el archivo de estilos

```
@import 'datatables.net-dt';
@import 'datatables.net-responsive-dt';
```